# PHP + ImageMagick Performance Issues

Tags: php, debian, php5, imagemagick

Good Day,

I have two environments: OpenVZ VPS and Pentium 4 local dev machine.

They have all packages installed the same way. ImageMagick is compiled from sources without OpenMP support.

When I run `time convert 'image.jpg' -resize "x60" -crop "60x60" +repage 'thumb'` the results are similar on both machines:

```
real    0m0.059s
user    0m0.047s
sys     0m0.012s
```

However, I face an issue with using ImageMagick with PHP via imagick PECL extension on the VPS. On the local environment response time is circa 50ms, on the VPS it's way too high: about 3 seconds.

No errors in logs.

Any ideas what could be wrong in here?

Cheers,
Stojko

Comment: Can you post the contents of /proc/user_beancounters? Could be something there. How much CPU and Ram have you allocated to the VPS, compared to what's available?